# microsoft virtual server multiple cpu configuration

Tags: virtualization, microsoft-virtual-server

How can i configure multiple virtual cpu in microsoft virtual server 2005R2. If there is any other virtual server which supports multiple virtual CPUs please let me know.

Comment: Can you be more specific please, what are you trying to achieve - there's bound to be lots of great options for you, VS2k5 is WAY old and everyone's years ahead of it, but let's pick you the right product by understanding your requirements fully first.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  The product doesn't support multiple virtual CPUs within a single VM.

Since you asked, almost any virtualization product issued in the last few years supports multiple virtual CPUs.  Since you're already using Microsoft's virtualization, you should probably look at Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft "Virtual Machine Emulated Hardware"

> If Virtual Server is run on a multiprocessor hardware system, each
>   hosted virtual machine session will only have a single CPU available
>   to it in its emulated hardware environment.
>
> Virtual Server can
>   distribute virtual machine sessions amongst multiple processors if
>   available, but each session will only have a single emulated processor
>   available to it.

You can read it here:

[Microsoft Virtual Server 2005 Virtual Machine Emulated Hardware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368891(v=vs.85).aspx)